# Adjust application resolution for mobile screens

Tags: mobile, qml, qt5, resolution, qtquick2

Hello I have tried to adjust my QML app for mobile screens. I have main screen which consists of `Tab`s in `TabView` :

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
TabView {
    Tab{
      id: Tab1 
      component: Qt.createComponent("qrc:///LoginScreen.qml")}
    Tab{
      id: Tab1
      component: Qt.createComponent("qrc:///AfterLogged.qml")}}`
```

In `LoginScreen.qml` in which I have `Button`s, `Label`s, `TextField`s to get data:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
Item { 
  Label {
    id: ipAddressLabel
    text: qsTr("Address IP:")
  TextField {
    id: ipTextField
    placeholderText: qsTr("Insert IP address")
  Button {
    id: loginBtn
    onClicked: {
     connectToApp(ipTextField.text)}}
    }
```

How could I resize my app screen on the basis of the specific mobile screen resolution/density?

Comment: IMHO this is not an easy question. Do you know this [info](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/scalability.html)? It's important to use `Qt Quick Layouts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have a look at the [`Screen`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-screen.html) type.

It contains the current `height` and `width` of your screen which can be assigned to your `LoginScreen.qml` `width` and `height` properties:

```
Item {
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height

    //[...]
}
```

Please note if you want to use `anchors` with margins you have to go a step deeper and calculate the margins correctly.